# Indesign - textframes to repeat

Tags: adobe-indesign

I’m having issues with repeating text frames with autoflow pages in InDesign and thought you may have a solution.
The document I'm looking to create will be 300+ pages of information, extracted from an excel sheet. Creating a shortcut is essential as I have a short time to create this and fit the data design.

I can get a single text frame to flow in a continuous stream of pages after importing an XML sample.

When separating tags into threaded text frames,  InDesign doesn’t recognise that there were 2 text frames within the template- it continues on the second text frame.

Comment: can you have one text frame with two columns? maybe put that on the master page?

Comment: already tried
also tried to change settings for a primary text frame

Comment: That may sound like a dumb question but did you thread your frames in your master spread?

Comment: Also, have you checked keep options? If you make threading visible, is threading ok (even to odd, to even and so on....) or is it threading only odd pages? Please provide more info...

Comment: Might this enlight you ? http://www.ozalto.com/en/5-errors-you-will-do-with-indesign-xml/

Comment: Are you using Data Merge from Utilites in Indesign?